# How do i make Onclick of a button based on its Text?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

The process I need is Like I have a array of buttons and I need to make the same on click function for every button which gets the text of the button which is clicked and parse it to an int and does Scene Management. Here is the short story of the function

Onclick -> array of buttons -> find button which is clicked -> get component children text -> parse as an int -> int = variable ->

```
SceneManager.LoadScene.(SceneManager.GetActiveScene.BuildIndex + variable)
```

Cheers!

Comment: You may need to read [ask]. I don't understand what you're asking. Can you flesh out the code a little?

Comment: set button on click to a method -> method has a array of all buttons -> get the button which triggered the method -> get button's component in children (TEXT) -> parse UI.Text to int -> set int to an variable Hope You Understand. Sorry for the bad english I am 14 and from a non english speaking country

Comment: I appreciate English is not your first language. The part I'm not getting is the `set int to an variable`. Can you please edit your question and show all the code you can write and just write pseudo-code for what you can't?

Comment: The Integer got should be set to an variable LIKE if 1 is the integer Variable = 1 thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show all the code you can write and just write pseudo-code for what you can't?

Comment: Pls see the below answer provided by ferderico and Its comment Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's your solution.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MyClass: MonoBehaviour
{
   public Button[] buttons;

   void OnEnable()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
      {
         buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate { LoadScene(i); });
      }
   }

   private void LoadScene(int i)
   {
      string text = buttons[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text;
      int number = int.Parse(text);

      SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene.BuildIndex + number);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I get a Index Out of Range Exception Index was outside the bounds of the array error at the below line of code `         string text = buttons[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text; `  Thanks! @federico-dondi

Comment: Be sure that every button has a child with a Text component attached. Also, remember to populate the `buttons` array.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `GetComponentInChildren<Text>` instead of `GetChild(0)`

Comment: That's an option for sure, it also make the code more readable.

Comment: It did not work. I am changing to manual scenemanagement. Thanks!